# How to pass array of custom type in oracle procedure in pl sql

Tags: arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am writing a pl/sql procedure in oracle to send automatic email with multiple attachments for that i Wrote a process where i am using following logic :

```
TYPE attach_info IS RECORD (
        attach_name     VARCHAR2(100),
        data_type       VARCHAR2(100) DEFAULT 'text/plain',
        attach_content  BLOB DEFAULT NULL
    );

TYPE array_attachments IS TABLE OF attach_info;
attachments array_attachments := array_attachments();
```

here I am defining type than like below define array size

```
attachments.extend(3);
```

and below code i retrieving attachment info and sent it for sending email

```
FOR i IN attachments.FIRST .. attachments.LAST
LOOP
-- Attach info
    UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(l_mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf));
    UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(l_mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Content-Type: ' || attachments(i).data_type
                        || ' name="'|| attachments(i).attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf));
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(l_mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'
                        || attachments(i).attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf));

-- Attach body       
  FOR j IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(attachments(i).attach_content) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(attachments(i).attach_content, l_step, j * l_step + 1))));
  END LOOP;

     UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
END LOOP;
```

now i want to make this process as generic to I can use this process many place,
So My question is how can i define this type for attachment, how I populate then and how can I pass this array of attachments in process so i can send them.

Comment: I don't follow. How more generic do you want the structure to be? It already is generic - it allows for arbitrary number of attachments with arbitrary content and arbitrary name and content type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type to create a parameter for a PLSQL function or procedure

```
procedure send(p_address varchar2,p_subject varchar2, p_attachments array_attachments)
```